# 17.10: Accidental clicks when trying to two-finger scroll quickly

Tags: touchpad, 17.10, scrolling, wayland, libinput

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10 I've been getting a lot of accidental clicks when using the "two-finger flick" gesture to scroll up and down. (I use both *Tap to click* and *Two-finger scroll*.)

This is really annoying - you often use many flick gestures quickly to scroll through a web page so it's quite likely you'll end up unintentionally left- and right-clicking things on the way. Many interactive websites, e.g. Trello, GitHub, Google Calendar, have a lot of click targets in areas that are also scrollable and when clicked these targets move, modify and delete things.

Two-finger scrolling was working fine for me in 17.04 - no accidental clicks detected.

I believe it's using the `libinput` driver for my touchpad:

```
$ grep -e "Using input driver 'libinput'" ~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log
[    17.394] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    17.395] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[    17.396] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    17.397] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Sleep Button'
[    17.398] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'HD Pro Webcam C920'
[    17.399] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'TrulyErgonomic.com Truly Ergonomic Computer Keyboard'
[    17.400] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'TrulyErgonomic.com Truly Ergonomic Computer Keyboard'
[    17.403] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Eee PC WMI hotkeys'
[    19.865] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech Rechargeable Touchpad T650'
[    22.098] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech Rechargeable Touchpad T650'
```

(also `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` is *not* installed).

Back on 17.04 I was using `libinput` then also. In fact I had experienced this exact problem (accidental clicks when scrolling) with the synaptics driver on 17.04, and switching to libinput on 17.04 fixed it. But on 17.10 it seems that now libinput has the same problem.

**Update:** Tried logging into X.org instead of Wayland, but the problem remains.

**Update:** Tested on a fresh 17.04 Live USB with the default session - same problem is there.